# Any chance to display KDE Task Switcher or all or only one attached monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde, task-switching

I am using comuter with multiple montiors. Any time I press Alt-Tab, task switcher appears on random monitor. While pressing alt tab it is impossible to understand, which window I am selecting. After I leave Alt-Tab and press it again, it appears on random monitor again. If I am using different visualization, it can appear bettween monitors in the middle.

This makes Alt-Tabl completely unusable on multiple monitor.

Is there any chance to fix this? Take example from MS Windows: task switcher appears either on one main monitor or on all ones.

Can the same be configured in KDE?

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible, I'm afraid. The task switcher can only show up on the monitor with the currently active window or the monitor where the mouse is on, depending on whether you uncheck or check the option "Active screen follows mouse" in System Settings > Window Management > Window Behavior > Focus tab.